# What is Cyclomatic Complexity?

Tags: language-agnostic, architecture, cyclomatic-complexity

A term that I see every now and then is "Cyclomatic Complexity". Here on SO I saw some Questions about "how to calculate the CC of Language X" or "How do I do Y with the minimum amount of CC", but I'm not sure I really understand what it is.

On the [NDepend Website](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#CC), I saw an explanation that basically says "The number of decisions in a method. Each if, for, && etc. adds +1 to the CC "score"). Is that really it? If yes, why is this bad? I can see that one might want to keep the number of if-statements fairly low to keep the code easy to understand, but is this really everything to it?

Or is there some deeper concept to it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I'm not aware of a deeper concept.  I believe it's generally considered in the context of a maintainability index.  The more branches there are within a particular method, the more difficult it is to maintain a mental model of that method's operation (generally).

Methods with higher cyclomatic complexity are also more difficult to obtain full code coverage on in unit tests.  (Thanks [Mark W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102529/marc-w)!)

That brings all the other aspects of maintainability in, of course.  Likelihood of errors/regressions/so forth.  The core concept is pretty straight-forward, though.

Comment: Also, the harder it is to unit test and gain complete code coverage.

Comment: Right 'cause they say you can only keep a handful of things in your conscience mind at any given moment.

Comment: The cyclomatic complexity of a method also denotes the number of unit test cases required to achieve the 100% code coverage for that method.

Comment: `'The more branches there are within a particular method'`... by this you mean more IF-Else statements?

Answer (score 42):

Cyclomatic complexity measures the number of times you must execute a block of code with varying parameters in order to execute every path through that block. A higher count is bad because it increases the chances for logical errors escaping your testing strategy.

Answer (score 14):

```
Cyclocmatic complexity = Number of decision points + 1
```

The decision points may be your conditional statements like if, if … else, switch , for loop, while loop etc.

The following chart describes the type of the application.

- Cyclomatic Complexity lies 1 – 10  To be considered Normal
  applicatinon
- Cyclomatic Complexity lies 11 – 20  Moderate application
- Cyclomatic Complexity lies 21 – 50  Risky application
- Cyclomatic Complexity lies more than 50  Unstable application

Comment: *"Cyclocmatic complexity = Number of decision points + 1"* For all cases I've tried, it seems to hold true. I have just one question: why do we bother with flow graphs and formulas, when `decision_points+1` is all we need? (At any rate, thanks for this extremely easy method!)

Answer (score 11):

Wikipedia may be your friend on this one: [Definition of cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)

Basically, you have to imagine your program as a [control flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) and then

> The complexity is (...) defined as:
>
> ```
> M = E − N + 2P
> ```
>
> where
>
> - M = cyclomatic complexity,
> - E = the number of edges of the graph
> - N = the number of nodes of the graph
> - P = the number of connected components

CC is a concept that attempts to capture how complex your program is and how hard it is to test it in a single integer number.

Answer (score 7):

Yep, that's really it. The more execution paths your code can take, the more things that must be tested, and the higher probability of error.

Answer (score 5):

Another interesting point I've heard:

The places in your code with the biggest indents should have the highest CC. These are generally the most important areas to ensure testing coverage because it's expected that they'll be harder to read/maintain. As other answers note, these are also the more difficult regions of code to ensure coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Cyclomatic Complexity really is just a scary buzzword. In fact it's a measure of code complexity used in software development to point out more complex parts of code (more likely to be buggy, and therefore has to be very carefully and thoroughly tested). You can calculate it using the E-N+2P formula, but I would suggest you have this calculated automatically by a plugin. I have heard of a rule of thumb that you should strive to keep the CC below 5 to maintain good readability and maintainability of your code.

I have just recently experimented with the [Eclipse Metrics Plugin](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/) on my Java projects, and it has a really nice and concise Help file which will of course integrate with your regular Eclipse help and you can read some more definitions of various complexity measures and tips and tricks on improving your code.

Answer (score 2):

That's it, the idea is that a method which has a low CC has less forks, looping etc which all make a method more complex. Imagine reviewing  500,000 lines of code, with an analyzer and seeing a couple methods which have oder of magnitude higher CC. This lets you then focus on refactoring those methods for better understanding (It's also common that a high CC has a high bug rate)

Answer (score 2):

Each decision point in a routine (loop, switch, if, etc...) essentially boils down to an if statement equivalent.  For each `if` you have 2 codepaths that can be taken.  So with the 1st branch there's 2 code paths, with the second there are 4 possible paths, with the 3rd there are 8 and so on.  There are at least 2**N code paths where N is the number of branches.

This makes it difficult to understand the behavior of code and to test it when N grows beyond some small number.

Answer (score 2):

The answers provided so far do not mention the correlation of software quality to cyclomatic complexity.  Research has shown that having a lower cyclomatic complexity metric should help develop software that is of higher quality.  It can help with software quality attributes of readability, maintainability, and portability. In general one should attempt to obtain a cyclomatic complexity metric of between 5-10.

One of the reasons for using metrics like cyclomatic complexity is that in general a human being can only keep track of about 7 (plus or minus 2) pieces of information simultaneously in your brain.  Therefore, if your software is overly complex with multiple decision paths, it is unlikely that you will be able to visualize how your software will behave (i.e. it will have a high cyclomatic complexity metric). This would most likely lead to developing erroneous or bug ridden software.  More information about this can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/cyclomatic-complexity.html) and also on [Wikipedia](http://One%20of%20the%20reasons%20for%20using%20metrics%20like%20cyclomatic%20complexity%20is%20that%20in%20general%20a%20human%20being%20can%20only%20keep%20track%20of%20about%207%20%28plus%20or%20minus%202%29%20pieces%20of%20information%20simultaneously%20in%20your%20brain.%20%20Therefore,%20if%20your%20software%20is%20overly%20complex%20with%20multiple%20decision%20paths,%20it%20is%20unlikely%20that%20you%20will%20be%20able%20to%20visualize%20how%20your%20software%20will%20behave%20%28i.e.%20it%20will%20have%20a%20high%20cyclomatic%20complexity%20metric%29.%20This%20would%20most%20likely%20lead%20to%20developing%20erroneous%20or%20bug%20ridden%20software.%20%20More%20information%20about%20this%20can%20be%20found%20here%20and%20also%20on%20Wikipedia.).

Answer (score 2):

Cyclomatic complexity is computed using the control flow graph. The Number of quantitative measure of linearly independent paths through a program's source code is called as Cyclomatic Complexity ( if/ if else / for / while )

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [control flow graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) of your function, with an additional edge running from the exit to the entrance. The cyclomatic complexity is the maximum number of cuts we can make without separating the graph into two pieces.

For example:

```
function F:
    if condition1:
       ...
    else:
       ...
    if condition2:
       ...
    else:
       ...
```

[image: Control Flow Graph]

[Control Flow Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Control_flow_graph_of_function_with_two_if_else_statements.svg)

You can probably intuitively see why the linked graph has a cyclomatic complexity of 3.

Comment: can you explain how and where are you making the cuts in the above diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Cyclomatric complexity is basically a metric to figure out areas of code that needs more attension for the maintainability. It would be basically an input to the refactoring.
It definitely gives an indication of code improvement area in terms of avoiding deep nested loop, conditions etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's sort of it. However, each branch of a "case" or "switch" statement tends to count as 1. In effect, this means CC *hates* case statements, and any code that requires them (command processors, state machines, etc).

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni - *May* yes. The problem is my typical command processor is reading commands from some external source, so I can't just let the compiler put data items wherever it wants like it must for a dynamic polymorphic class.

Answer (score 0):

Cyclomatric complexity is a measure of how complex a unit of software is.It measures the number of different paths a program might follow with conditional logic constructs (If ,while,for,switch & cases etc....). If you will like to learn more about calculating it here is a wonderful youtube video you can watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlCGomvu-NM

It is important in designing test cases because it reveals the different paths or scenarios a program can take .
"To have good testability and maintainability, McCabe recommends
that no program module should exceed a cyclomatic complexity of 10"(Marsic,2012, p. 232).

Reference:
Marsic., I. (2012, September). *Software Engineering*. Rutgers University. Retrieved from www.ece.rutgers.edu/~marsic/books/SE/book-SE_marsic.pdf