# Calculating Cyclomatic Complexity [Pseudocode]

Tags: pseudocode, cyclomatic-complexity

The Cyclomatic Complexity of the pseudocode below is "4".

```
Read A
Read B
IF A > 0 THEN
     IF B  = 0 THEN
    Print “No values”
     ELSE
    Print B
    IF A > 21 THEN
        Print A
    ENDIF
     ENDIF
ENDIF
```

How do we count it? 
I heard that it's # of conditions + 1?  Do we count those else statements? I'm confused.

EDIT: 
Case 2:
What if we have:

```
IF (x < y)
statment 1

IF (x < z)
statemnt 2
```

What will be the Cyclomatic complexity?  2? or 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Cyclomatic Complexity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911637/what-is-cyclomatic-complexity)

Comment: For Case 2 the answer is 3 becuase of Equation **M = Total Condition Count + 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Main flow + 3 x '`If`'s = 4

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity):

> The cyclomatic complexity of a section of source code is the count of
> the number of linearly independent paths through the source code. For
> instance, if the source code contained no decision points such as IF
> statements or FOR loops, the complexity would be 1, since there is
> only a single path through the code.
>
> If the code had a single IF
> statement containing a single condition there would be two paths
> through the code, one path where the IF statement is evaluated as TRUE
> and one path where the IF statement is evaluated as FALSE.