# Available Code Metric Systems?

Tags: code-metrics

Besides Cyclomatic Complexity what other code metric systems exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Code metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972259/code-metrics)

[Do you find cyclomatic complexity a useful measure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745857/do-you-find-cyclomatic-complexity-a-useful-measure)

[What code metric(s) convince you that provided code is “crappy”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187289/what-code-metrics-convince-you-that-provided-code-is-crappy)

Comment: This is an *accepted* answer?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia provides a
[simple overview of metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_metric).

There are actually lots, and lots of metrics.  In fact, *any* function of the source code that maps source code to a measurement scale (integers, reals, classification enums) can be considered to be a metric.

The problem with most code metrics  is that they tend to be proportional to SLOC, and if that's the case, SLOC is just as good.  What is best to do with metrics is to measure your code now, and track how the metric changes over time; the trend, up or down, will tell you almost more than the metric will itself.  Up means bad news; the code is getting more complicated.

It is also useful to consider code (complexity) metrics in conjunction with bug rates.  A high complexity in a module, *and* and high bug rate in the same module, suggests that a redesign of that module may be a good idea to prevent further troubles in the field.  High complexity and low bug rates would suggest the code looks scary but isn't.

Answer (score 1):

[Halstead's Software Science](http://yunus.hacettepe.edu.tr/~sencer/complexity.html) is a fantastic metrics suite that can give you interesting insight into the actual constructs of your program.

There is a model created by Card and Glass as well, but I'm not sure if that is available outside of books. I would look for it regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 82 [code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx) definitions supported by the tool NDepend integrated in Visual Studio 2012, 2010 and 2008. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

Notice that these code metrics can be composed through [CQLinq queries and rules](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) to define your own custom code metrics.

For example, one popular code metric other than *Cyclomatic Complexity* is the [*C.R.A.P* metric](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=215899). Basically, the *C.R.A.P* define crappy code as complex methods (with high *Cyclomatic Complexity*), poorly covered by tests. The [default CQLinq rule](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_C.R.A.P_method_code_metric.html) to define the *C.R.A.P* metric is:

```
// <Name>C.R.A.P method code metric</Name>
// Change Risk Analyzer and Predictor (i.e. CRAP) code metric
// This code metric helps in pinpointing overly complex and untested code.
// Reference: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=215899
// Formula:   CRAP(m) = comp(m)^2 * (1 – cov(m)/100)^3 + comp(m)
warnif count > 0
from m in JustMyCode.Methods

// Don't match too short methods
where m.NbLinesOfCode > 10

let CC = m.CyclomaticComplexity
let uncov = (100 - m.PercentageCoverage) / 100f
let CRAP = (CC * CC * uncov * uncov * uncov) + CC
where CRAP != null && CRAP > 30
orderby CRAP descending, m.NbLinesOfCode descending
select new { m, CRAP, CC, uncoveredPercentage = uncov*100, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```